# AWS Lambda function from MS Teams

Tags: aws-lambda, microsoft-teams, pagerduty

Is there a way we can trigger AWS Lambda function from MS Teams?

I need a notification from the Microsoft Teams channel to flip to Pager Duty. Will he be able to grasp it through AWS Lamdba? On Teams I have all notifications about events from Gitlab and Github and integration in PG only supports merge request for GL and pull request for GH.

Comment: Do you need to trigger a lambda from Teams, or from a GL or GH event? If you're needing it from Teams, are you wanting a user to take some action in Teams to trigger the lambda?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Ideally, it should be done without user integration in Teams.

Comment: Why not go directly from GH/GL to lambda? What is the value of having Teams in the middle of that?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth If it is possible to handle it directly from GH and GL, Teams is no longer needed. How to do it?

Comment: GH and GL are just making HTTP calls. You can have them call an API Gateway and back that with a lambda.

Comment: @caprio, are you still facing the issue.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT I don't know how to start. So I have to create Github webhook, API Gateway, Lambda, SNS.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [sending messages to teams channel using webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using)? Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Moving comments to answer section for better visibility.

You can also use this JSON to create cards containing rich inputs, such as text entry, multi-select, or picking a date and time. The code that generates the card and posts to the webhook URL can be running on any hosted service. These cards are defined as part of actionable messages, and are also supported in cards used in Teams bots and Messaging extensions.